# Java API for KML (JAK) embedding images in kmz files

Tags: java, kml, kmz, jak

Is there a way to just add an image file into a kmz file using Java API for KML (JAK)? I can create a kml file with no problem, but I'm trying to just embed a resources (such as an images folder with some image files), but the marshalAsKmz method takes only Kml objects as additional files, so I can't figure out how to just include extra images.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've been using JAK for over a year on a project. I use it to create the KML, then I marshal it as just plain KML (not KMZ). I created a separate utility class that uses the Java SE 'Zip' classes to manually create the KMZ. It works just fine. A KMZ is nothing more than a .zip archive that contains exactly one .kml file and 0 or more resource files (such as images, etc). The only difference is that you name the file as .kmz instead of .zip when you output it. In the KML document `<Style>` definitions, refer to your resources files with paths relative to the KML document itself. The KML file is considered to be at the 'root' of the KMZ archive. If your resource files are also located in the root of the KMZ (.zip) then you don't need a path, just the filename.

**EDIT:** *I actually forgot that I removed the intermediate step of marshalling the JAK `Kml` object to a file before I zip it. My utility method below will marshal the `Kml` object directly to the `ZipOutputStream`.*

Here is a utility class that I created to do just what I have described. I'm posting it here in the hope that someone else posts an alternate solution that uses only JAK so I can retire this code in the future. For now, this will do the job for you.

**NOTE: If you don't use slf4j, Apache Commons Lang or Commons I/O then just make a few adjustments to the code to remove/replace those bits with your own code. Obviously this code requires the JAK library.**

```
package com.jimtough;

import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.zip.ZipEntry;
import java.util.zip.ZipOutputStream;

import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;
import org.apache.commons.lang.Validate;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

import de.micromata.opengis.kml.v_2_2_0.Kml;

/**
 * Uses the classes in java.util.zip to package a KML file and its
 * supplementary files as a ZIP-compressed KMZ file.
 * 
 * @author JTOUGH
 */
public final class KMZPackager {

    private final static Logger logger =
        LoggerFactory.getLogger(KMZPackager.class);

    /**
     * Container for data that represents a single entry that will be added
     * to a compressed archive.
     * @author JTOUGH
     */
    public static abstract class DataSource {
        protected String archivedFileName;

        /**
         * Write the contents of this data source to the supplied
         * zip output stream.
         * 
         * @param zipOutputStream
         * @throws IOException
         */
        public abstract void writeToStream(ZipOutputStream zipOutputStream) 
            throws IOException; 
    }

    /**
     * Container for data that represents a single file that will be added
     * to a compressed archive.
     * @author JTOUGH
     */
    public static final class FileDataSource extends DataSource {
        private File sourceFile;

        /**
         * Constructor
         * 
         * @param sourceFile Actual file that will be added to the 
         *  compressed archive. 
         * @param archivedFileName Name that will be assigned to the compressed
         *  file within the archive. Caller must ensure that this value is
         *  unique within the archive otherwise an exception will be thrown
         *  when a name clash occurs during creation of the archive.
         *  This string must be non-null and non-empty. Any forward-slash
         *  characters in the string will be treated as directory separators
         *  when the KMZ/ZIP archive is created.
         * @throws IllegalArgumentException If either of these parameters
         *  is a null reference
         */
        public FileDataSource(
                File sourceFile,
                String archivedFileName) 
                throws IllegalArgumentException {
            Validate.notNull(sourceFile);
            Validate.notEmpty(archivedFileName);
            this.sourceFile = sourceFile;
            this.archivedFileName = archivedFileName;
        }

        @Override
        public void writeToStream(ZipOutputStream zipOutputStream)
                throws IOException {
            Validate.notNull(zipOutputStream);

            // Check that the file exists, and throw an appropriate exception
            // before reading it
            if (!sourceFile.exists()) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                    "File referenced in parameter [" +
                    sourceFile.getAbsolutePath() + "] does not exist");
            }

            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(sourceFile);

            if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
                logger.debug("Adding file to KMZ archive" +
                    " | archive name: " + archivedFileName +
                    " | original name: " + 
                    sourceFile.getCanonicalPath());
            }

            // Mark the start of this new file in the ZIP stream
            ZipEntry entry = new ZipEntry(archivedFileName);
            zipOutputStream.putNextEntry(entry);

            // Use the Apache commons-io library to do a buffered
            // stream-to-stream copy
            try {
                IOUtils.copy(fis, zipOutputStream);
            } finally {
                fis.close();
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Container for a single JAK Kml object that will be marshalled
     * directly to a compressed KMZ archive as it is created
     * @author JTOUGH
     */
    public static final class KMLDataSource extends DataSource {
        private Kml kml;

        /**
         * Constructor
         * 
         * @param kml JAK Kml object that will be marshalled directly to the 
         *  compressed archive. 
         * @param archivedFileName Name that will be assigned to the compressed
         *  file within the archive. Caller must ensure that this value is
         *  unique within the archive otherwise an exception will be thrown
         *  when a name clash occurs during creation of the archive.
         *  This string must be non-null and non-empty. Any forward-slash
         *  characters in the string will be treated as directory separators
         *  when the KMZ/ZIP archive is created.
         * @throws IllegalArgumentException If either of these parameters
         *  is a null reference
         */
        public KMLDataSource(
                Kml kml,
                String archivedFileName) 
                throws IllegalArgumentException {
            Validate.notNull(kml);
            Validate.notEmpty(archivedFileName);
            this.kml = kml;
            this.archivedFileName = archivedFileName;
        }

        @Override
        public void writeToStream(ZipOutputStream zipOutputStream) throws IOException {
            Validate.notNull(zipOutputStream);
            // Mark the start of this new file in the ZIP stream
            ZipEntry entry = new ZipEntry(archivedFileName);
            zipOutputStream.putNextEntry(entry);

            // Marshal the Kml object directly to the ZipOutputStream
            if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
                logger.debug("Marshalling KML to KMZ archive" +
                    " | archive name: " + archivedFileName);
            }
            kml.marshal(zipOutputStream);   
        }
    }

    /**
     * Container for a stream holding a Kml document. This will be written
     * directly to a compressed KMZ archive as it is created.
     */
    public static final class StreamDataSource extends DataSource {

        private InputStream inputStream;

        /**
         * Constructor
         * 
         * @param inputStream the inputStream holding the KML text
         * @param archivedFileName Name that will be assigned to the compressed
         *  file within the archive. Caller must ensure that this value is
         *  unique within the archive otherwise an exception will be thrown
         *  when a name clash occurs during creation of the archive.
         *  This string must be non-null and non-empty. Any forward-slash
         *  characters in the string will be treated as directory separators
         *  when the KMZ/ZIP archive is created.
         * @throws IllegalArgumentException If either of these parameters
         *  is a null reference
         */
        public StreamDataSource(
                InputStream inputStream,
                String archivedFileName) 
                throws IllegalArgumentException {
            Validate.notNull(inputStream);
            Validate.notEmpty(archivedFileName);
            this.inputStream = inputStream;
            this.archivedFileName = archivedFileName;
        }

        @Override
        public void writeToStream(ZipOutputStream zipOutputStream) throws IOException {
            Validate.notNull(zipOutputStream);
            // Mark the start of this new file in the ZIP stream
            ZipEntry entry = new ZipEntry(archivedFileName);
            zipOutputStream.putNextEntry(entry);

            // Use the Apache commons-io library to do a buffered
            // stream-to-stream copy
            if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
                logger.debug("Copying KML from stream to KMZ archive" +
                    " | archive name: " + archivedFileName);
            }
            try {
                IOUtils.copy(inputStream, zipOutputStream);
            } finally {
                inputStream.close();
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Use ZIP compression to package a KML file and its supplementary files
     * as a KMZ archive.  The compressed archive will be written to the 
     * supplied output stream.
     * 
     * @param os OutputStream to which the compressed archive will be written.
     *  This parameter must be a non-null reference to an OutputStream that
     *  is open for write operations.
     * @param kmlDataSource KML to be added to the compressed archive. 
     *  This parameter must not be null. The archivedFileName attribute must
     *  end with the .kml extension. The file is added to the compressed 
     *  archive. The KMZ specification states that a KMZ archive must only
     *  contain a single KML file.
     * @param supplementaryFileList List of file locations for supplementary
     *  files that will be included in the KMZ archive. A common example
     *  would be icons or image overlays that are referenced in the KML file.
     *  This parameter can be null or an empty list if there are no 
     *  supplementary files to include in the KMZ. Each source that is included
     *  in the list must refer to an existing file that does NOT have the
     *  file extension '.kml'.
     * @throws RuntimeException Thrown if anything unexpected occurs
     *  that prevents execution from continuing or if any of the stated
     *  conditions for the input parameters are violated
     */
    public void packageAsKMZ(
            OutputStream os,
            DataSource kmlDataSource,
            List<FileDataSource> supplementaryFileList) 
            throws RuntimeException {
        ZipOutputStream zipOutputStream = null;
        boolean isExceptionThrown = false;
        Exception caughtException = null;
        List<FileDataSource> supplFileList = supplementaryFileList;

        try {
            Validate.notNull(os, "os parameter cannot be null");
            Validate.notNull(kmlDataSource, 
                "kmlFileDataSource parameter cannot be null");

            // Treat a null parameter just like an empty list (which is OK)
            if (supplFileList == null) {
                supplFileList = Collections.emptyList();
            }

            if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
                logger.debug(
                    "Creating KMZ archive" +
                    " | supplementary files: " + supplFileList.size());
            }

            // Create a buffered output stream for the new KMZ file
            zipOutputStream = new ZipOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(os));
            Validate.isTrue(
                kmlDataSource.archivedFileName.endsWith(".kml"),
                "KML archived file name must end with .kml");
            kmlDataSource.writeToStream(zipOutputStream);

            // Now process the list of supplementary files
            if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
                logger.debug("Adding supplementary files to KMZ archive" +
                    " | archive name: ");
            }
            for (FileDataSource ds : supplFileList) {
                Validate.isTrue(
                    !ds.archivedFileName.endsWith(".kml"),
                    "Not legal to include .kml files in supplementary list");
                ds.writeToStream(zipOutputStream);
            }

            // Close the output stream to complete the ZIP creation
            zipOutputStream.flush();
            zipOutputStream.close();

            logger.info("KMZ archive created successfully");

        } catch (IOException e) {
            isExceptionThrown = true;
            caughtException = e;
            logger.error("IOException while creating ZIP stream");
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            isExceptionThrown = true;
            caughtException = e;
        } catch (RuntimeException e) {
            isExceptionThrown = true;
            caughtException = e;
        } finally {
            if (isExceptionThrown) {
                try {
                    if (zipOutputStream != null) {
                        zipOutputStream.close();
                    }
                } catch (IOException ioe) {
                    // Don't care
                }
                throw new RuntimeException(caughtException);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Java comes with a default zip utility, all you need to do is to pass the kml file you need to zip along with the list of image files. These two functions should do the trick.

```
   private void exportAsKmz(Kml kmlFile,File[] files) throws IOException {
      ZipOutputStream out = new ZipOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("example.kmz"));
      addKmzFile(kmlFile,out,files);
      out.close();
   }

   private void addKmzFile(Kml kmzFile, ZipOutputStream out,File[] files) throws IOException {
      String fileName = "";
      fileName = kmzFile.getFeature().getName();
      if (!fileName.endsWith(".kml")) {
         fileName += ".kml";
      }
      for(File file : files){
         out.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(file.getName()));
         Files.copy(file.toPath(), out);
      }
      out.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(URLEncoder.encode(fileName, "UTF-8")));
      kmzFile.marshal(out);
      out.closeEntry();
   }
```